# Split a set to sub sets using Lists.partition or Iterable.partition

Tags: java, list, set, iterable, partition

I was wondering what is the efficient way to split a set into sub sets?

```
Iterable<List<Long>> partitions = Iterables.partition(numbers, 10);
```

OR

```
List<List<Long>> partitions = Lists.partition(numbers, 10);
```

What is the difference in Time Complexity?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the inner implementation

[method partition() for iterables](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.529)

```
529  public static <T> Iterable<List<T>> partition(final Iterable<T> iterable, final int size) {
530    checkNotNull(iterable);
531    checkArgument(size > 0);
532    return new FluentIterable<List<T>>() {
533      @Override
534      public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
535        return Iterators.partition(iterable.iterator(), size);
536      }
537    };
538  }
```

[method partition() for Lists](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#line.681)

```
681  public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int size) {
682    checkNotNull(list);
683    checkArgument(size > 0);
684    return (list instanceof RandomAccess)
685        ? new RandomAccessPartition<T>(list, size)
686        : new Partition<T>(list, size);
687  }
```

In the above 2 implementations, if you analyse the code, `Lists` checks for `list instanceof RandomAccess` and if it's true, then RandomAccess Interface is used to evaluate the partition.

Now if we see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) of RandomAccess:

> **public interface RandomAccess**
>    Marker interface used by List implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant
>   time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow
>   generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance
>   when applied to either random or sequential access lists.

So, I guess the latter have better performance.

---

What if our `list` isn't an instance of `RandomAccess` interface?

The core class used by `Lists` to perform partition ([source](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#line.689))

```
689  private static class Partition<T> extends AbstractList<List<T>> {
690    final List<T> list;
691    final int size;
692
693    Partition(List<T> list, int size) {
694      this.list = list;
695      this.size = size;
696    }
697
698    @Override
699    public List<T> get(int index) {
700      checkElementIndex(index, size());
701      int start = index * size;
702      int end = Math.min(start + size, list.size());
703      return list.subList(start, end);
704    }
705
706    @Override
707    public int size() {
708      return IntMath.divide(list.size(), size, RoundingMode.CEILING);
709    }
710
711    @Override
712    public boolean isEmpty() {
713      return list.isEmpty();
714    }
715  }
```

and the core class used by `Iterators` to perform partition([source](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#line.605))

```
605  private static <T> UnmodifiableIterator<List<T>> partitionImpl(
606      final Iterator<T> iterator, final int size, final boolean pad) {
607    checkNotNull(iterator);
608    checkArgument(size > 0);
609    return new UnmodifiableIterator<List<T>>() {
610      @Override
611      public boolean hasNext() {
612        return iterator.hasNext();
613      }
614      @Override
615      public List<T> next() {
616        if (!hasNext()) {
617          throw new NoSuchElementException();
618        }
619        Object[] array = new Object[size];
620        int count = 0;
621        for (; count < size && iterator.hasNext(); count++) {
622          array[count] = iterator.next();
623        }
624        for (int i = count; i < size; i++) {
625          array[i] = null; // for GWT
626        }
627
628        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we only put Ts in it
629        List<T> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(
630            (List<T>) Arrays.asList(array));
631        return (pad || count == size) ? list : list.subList(0, count);
632      }
633    };
634  }
```

Now if we analyze the last 2 codes, it's really not easy for anyone to figure out which would be better without doing comprehensive analysis. However, we can say that if our list is an instance of `RandomAccess` interface, then definitely `Lists.partition(lists, pivot);` is faster.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. but I have a set and not list. So how can I use the Lists.partition?

Comment: @userit1985 I am not aware of any `guava` library that would support partitioning the `Set`s because `Set`s do not guarantee the order of iteration, no assumptions can be made about the sequence of which partitions would arrive in. You can read more about it in [this issue on github.](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1079)